Pointwise Convergence Definition Question
The definition of a sequence converging to a function on a set X is as follows:

For all $\epsilon>0$ and for all $x\in X$, there exists a natural number $N$, such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.

But how about if $f(x)=\infty$? How does "every $\epsilon$" hold in this instance?

You can consider $\infty$ as added to $\mathbb{R}$, where the neighbourhoods of $\infty$ are of the form $(m,\infty]$, instead of $(f(x) - \varepsilon, f(x) + \varepsilon)$. This way, the definition becomes: for every $m$ there exist $N$ such that $f_n(x) \in (m,\infty]$ for all $n\geq N$.

Thank you, so basically, the definition above only applies to finite point of convergence?

Yes your definition is only for finite point. It's better to think of convergence in terms of open sets https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)#Topological_space, this way the definition is uniform for every case. The basic open neighbourhoods of $\infty$ are $(x, \infty]$, and the basic open neighbourhoods of a finite number $x$ is $(x-\varepsilon, x + \varepsilon)$.

The underlying issue is that you're assuming a certain space and metric. Namely:

You're assuming $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and I can tell this because of that concern and...
You're assuming the distance between points $x,y \in X$ is measured by the absolute value: $d(x,y) := |x-y|$

More broadly, in a metric space [1] $(X,d)$, we can define convergence of a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq X$ to a point $x \in X$ as so:
$$
(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists N \in \mathbb{N})(\forall n \ge N) \Big( x_n \in B_\varepsilon(x) \Big)
$$
where we define the open ball centered at $x$ and with radius $\varepsilon$ by
$$
B_\varepsilon(x) := \{ z \in X \mid d(x,z) < \varepsilon \}
$$
If we consider $X = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$, it is no longer a metric space under the usual absolute value, since the distance between $\infty$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}$ can only reasonably be defined as $\infty$, but metrics need to have finite outputs.
One can define a metric on $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$ that makes it behave like [2] $[0,1]$ though. Namely, if we let
$$\begin{align*}
f:\mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\} &\to \left[-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2\right] \\
x &\mapsto f(x):=\begin {cases} 
-\frac \pi 2 & x=-\infty\\
\arctan x & -\infty \le x \le \infty \\
\frac \pi 2 & x=+\infty \end {cases}
\end{align*}$$
then a suitable metric is
$$
d(x,y):=|f(x)-f(y)|
$$
and, to recollection, your open balls end up looking like $[-\infty,a)$ and $(a,\infty]$ alongside the usual types.

In conclusion, then, for the definition you're using: you're assuming your functions map a set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$, so it's not possible or allowed for functions to have $f(x) = \pm \infty$.


Aside [1]: A metric space $(X,d)$ is a set $X$ with a function $d : X^2 \to [0,\infty)$ such that three criteria are met:

$d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ for all $x,y \in X$ (symmetry)
$d(x,y) = 0 \iff x=y$
$d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z)$ for all $x,y,z \in X$ (triangle inequality)



Aside [2]: Specifically, I mean the two spaces are "homeomorphic." Metric spaces $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\rho)$ are said to be homeomorphic if there is some function $h : X \to Y$ which is bijective, continuous, and has a continuous inverse.

